# How to solve $f(n) = \frac{9}{2}f(n-1) + \frac{9}{2}f(n-2) - \frac{81}{2}f(n-3) + \frac{81}{2}f(n-4) + n + 2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

How can I solve the recurrence relation below using generating functions?
$$f(n) = \frac{9}{2}f(n-1) + \frac{9}{2}f(n-2) - \frac{81}{2}f(n-3) + \frac{81}{2}f(n-4) + n + 2$$ $$f(0) = f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = 1$$
**Attempt:**

The generating function of (n+2) is $\frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$. So we can write our generating function this way, $f = \frac{9}{2}xf + \frac{9}{2}x^2f - \frac{81}{2}x^3f + \frac{81}{2}x^4f + \frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$.

Let's isolate f and get, $f(1 - \frac{9}{2}x - \frac{9}{2}x^2 + \frac{81}{2}x^3 - \frac{81}{2}x^4) = \frac{2-x}{(1-x)^2}$ and finally, $f = \frac{2-x}{(1 - \frac{9}{2}x - \frac{9}{2}x^2 + \frac{81}{2}x^3 - \frac{81}{2}x^4)(1-x)^2}$.

Here I got stuck.

Comment: How did you get *the very first* equality in your attempt? The recurrence clearly assumes $n\geqslant 4$ so that, multiplying it by $x^n$ and doing $\sum_{n=4}^\infty$, you should get $$f-1-x-x^2-x^3=\frac92x(f-1-x-x^2)+\frac92x^2(f-1-x)+\dots$$

Comment: Anyway, the next thing to find is the [PFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $f$. Factor its denominator...

Comment: You should give the sequence and its generating function two different names.  One is a function of $n$, and one is a different function of $x$.  Do not use $f$ for both.